# How do I use class variables in Clamato?

Tags: smalltalk

I discovered Clamato the other day and want to play a bit with it. I don't seem to find how one can declare and use class variables in Clamato. The docs only mention instance variables.

Here's the link to http://clamato.net/ if you didn't already know it.

Here's the source: http://bitbucket.org/avibryant/clamato/src

Comment: upvoting because I wish I knew smalltalk

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for discovering Tommy.
Will also give a play.
In regard to "class variables", your link above states that the language has "no metaclass hierarchy", so a guess would be no class variables, but could be wrong.

Comment: +1 But the answer feels incomplete. Is there an alternative to class variables? Singletons, globals?

Comment: @Alexandre Jasmin Is it possible to implement a singleton without using class variables? I don't think it is.

Comment: Assuming Clamato allows messaging to it's parent jscript environment, seems you could use 'global vars' anyway, much different than 'class vars' though. Could always kludge something in with naming. We'll have to play and see. Is Clamato though now "done" (maybe another question here)? Something about group being bought out... Good idea though, as an alternative to jquery, etc. jscript wrappers. If Clamato is done, maybe Tommy you can start another effort, and we'll help out as we can :)....

Comment: @Vijay I simply think of a singleton here as *some class with a single instance*, not the typical implementation pattern of a singleton where a reference to that single instance is kept in a class variable.

Comment: Makes sense Vijay. Maybe in Clamato, you would want to implement a 'Singleton' class (for access/release/etc of single object) and you could have one of those for each object you want a global (single) instance of. I think you're right, not much different than accessing via metaclass (from the client object perspective).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [amber](http://www.amber-lang.net), another smalltalk implementation for the web browser. It has a lot more traction, I've seen presentations at the [FOSDEM](http://www.fosdem.org) and [ESUG](http://www.esug.org) conferences